# How can I use conditional Template tags inside a Vue SFC

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

I have two modes of using my application, an embedded and non-embedded mode. For the embedded (think iframe) mode I don't want to show the site header and footer. I tried using v-if and v-else in App.vue but Visual Studio Code complains about having multiple template root elements. This seems like it should be allowed:

```
<template v-if="embedded">
  <div id="app">
    <MyContent/>
  </div>
</template>
<template v-else>
  <div id="app">
    <TheHeader/>
    <MyContent/>
    <TheFooter/>
  </div>
</template>
```

I'd appreciate any thoughts on this. Is it a bug in VS Code? Is this just not allowed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In vue2 with regular .vue files you must have a single root.  So you could accomplish this by wrapping the entire thing in a div.

```
<template>
  <div>  
    <template v-if="embedded">
      <div id="app">
        <MyContent/>
      </div>
    </template>
    <template v-else>
      <div id="app">
        <TheHeader/>
        <MyContent/>
        <TheFooter/>
      </div>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
```

You can also accomplish what you are saying using a functional component, but i would avoid that unless you are familiar with a more jsx style or have stronger js knowledge with hyperscript.  https://zendev.com/2018/05/07/multi-root-vue-components.html

NOTE: Vue3 has multiroot templates planned, so this should be possible in the future

Answer (score 1):

you can try below to load the components inside `<div id="app">` conditionally

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div v-if="embedded">
      <MyContent/>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <TheHeader/>
      <MyContent/>
      <TheFooter/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```